# Acknowledgments in google scholar citations

Tags: bibliometrics

Is it acceptable to add articles under my profile in "google scholar citation" in which i was acknowledged for my real contribution rather than being a co-author?

Answer (score 4):

Acceptable I'm not sure, but it really doesn't sound like a good idea.

The point of Google Scholar is to collect in one place the information on papers in which you are an author. If the paper in question was prominent enough in your profile to attract my attention, I would assume that something suspicious is going on, and there is no way for me to tell whose fault it is. Overall, it doesn't send the kind of signal you would probably want to send.

Answer (score 2):

Being acknowledge doesn't count as authorship and claiming otherwise will make you seem clueless or fraudulent.

This being said, Google Scholar is a search engine not a scientific vetting service, it doesn't have standards as to what constitute a publication or a citation. Certainly listing articles you didn’t author wouldn’t be the sketchiest thing I’ve seen on this service.

Comment: Your first paragraph isn't very good advice. I "can" (i.e. I have the ability to) claim on my website that I have solved the Riemann hypothesis by proving it was equivalent to P=NP and that I was awarded the Nobel peace prize for that. There are no "standards" preventing me from doing this. It will probably tank my career, however. Without going to such extremes, if an author of the paper sees their paper on a non-author's profile (and you can see whether the profile has been validated by the user), they might take it the wrong way.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I made some edits based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say that it's not acceptable, but now that I think about it a little more, the situation is a bit murkier.

If you are trying to do this to claim co-authorship on some high-impact papers in an attempt to boost your statistics and look like a more impressive candidate, this would be wrong. If the purpose is to draw attention to related work in which you participated, it's not nearly as problematic. I would still be unlikely to do it, just for the reason that there would be the question of "why am I listing a publication when I'm not an actual author.

Moreover, what level of contribution did you provide that was enough to merit an acknowledgment but not a co-authorship? (I had one or two of those, and I wouldn't bother to list it on a CV because it's just not worth it.)